# Why does this code not work with a named range?

Tags: excel, named-ranges, vba

I'm a VBA newbie and did not write this code, credit goes to Ron de Bruin. I'm using it to retrieve the value from whichever cells I enter into the Range - line 12, from whichever files I select. It works with cell locations but all my files have different locations for the defined names. But when I put a defined name into the range, ie. Set rng = Range("cName1") it doesn't work. So basically how would I modify it so I can put a named range in (but also works with a cell location if possible...) Thank you in advance for any help!!

```
Sub Summary_cells_from_Different_Workbooks_1()
    Dim FileNameXls As Variant
    Dim SummWks As Worksheet
    Dim ColNum As Integer
    Dim myCell As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim RwNum As Long, FNum As Long, FinalSlash As Long
    Dim ShName As String, PathStr As String
    Dim SheetCheck As String, JustFileName As String
    Dim JustFolder As String

    ShName = "Sheet1"  '<---- Change
    Set Rng = Range("D4:D20")   '<---- Change

    'Select the files with GetOpenFilename
    FileNameXls = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files, *.xl*", _
                                          MultiSelect:=True)

     If IsArray(FileNameXls) = False Then
        'do nothing
     Else
        With Application
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With

        'Add a new workbook with one sheet for the Summary
        Set SummWks = Workbooks.Add(1).Worksheets(1)

        'The links to the first workbook will start in row 2
        RwNum = 1

        For FNum = LBound(FileNameXls) To UBound(FileNameXls)
            ColNum = 1
            RwNum = RwNum + 1
            FinalSlash = InStrRev(FileNameXls(FNum), "\")
            JustFileName = Mid(FileNameXls(FNum), FinalSlash + 1)
            JustFolder = Left(FileNameXls(FNum), FinalSlash - 1)

            'copy the workbook name in column A
            SummWks.Cells(RwNum, 1).Value = JustFileName

            'build the formula string
            JustFileName = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(JustFileName, "'", "''")
            PathStr = "'" & JustFolder & "\[" & JustFileName & "]" & ShName & "'!"

            On Error Resume Next
            SheetCheck = ExecuteExcel4Macro(PathStr & Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1))
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                'If the sheet not exist in the workbook the row color will be Yellow.
                SummWks.Cells(RwNum, 1).Resize(1, Rng.Cells.Count + 1) _
                    .Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Else
                For Each myCell In Rng.Cells
                    ColNum = ColNum + 1
                    SummWks.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Formula = _
                    "=" & PathStr & myCell.Address
                Next myCell
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next FNum

        ' Use AutoFit to set the column width in the new workbook
        SummWks.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

        MsgBox "The Summary is ready, save the file if you want to keep it"

        With Application
            .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("NamedRange")` _does_ work.  If you are not getting the result you expect it's probably related to the definition of the named range

Comment: @chrisneilsen It won't work - because the code uses the **address** of the cells in `Range("NamedRange")` to create a formula to a non-opened workbook.  While it is using the address of something like A4:D10, it works (because A4:D10 is in the same location in every worksheet of every workbook) but, if `"NamedRange"` is a range name in that non-opened workbook, it is going to fail.

Comment: @YowE3K it works in the sense that if a named range called `NamedRange` exists in the active workbook and it's either Workbook scoped or Worksheet scoped and that sheet is active, and it refers to a range then it will return a result.  Whether it's what the result the OP wants is another question

Comment: True, but the question *does* state that the named range refers to different locations in different workbooks.  I've been scratching my head (while trying to pretend to work) about this ever since it was posted, and I don't think there is going to be any easy fix. (I don't think `INDIRECT` or `OFFSET` work on a closed workbook, although I haven't gotten up the energy to test that.)  I suspect that the code being used is just not suited for the task that is being done and a completely new piece of code will have to be written.

Comment: @YowE3K yes you're right, it does refer to different locations in different unopened workbooks. And I don't think INDIRECT will work. Back to the drawing board!  Thanks for you help guys!

Comment: Is the range a single cell?  Or a fixed number of rows and columns? Or is it completely "random" as to its size?

Comment: I think just multiple single cells if I understand what you're saying? for example i'd want to capture "Type", "Age", "Size", "Color", etc.. which are all named and have only one value (per file).

Comment: A "non-generic" piece of code could be written where you replaced the storing of things in the `For Each myCell In Rng.Cells` loop with statements such as `SummWks.Cells(RwNum, 2).Formula = "=" & PathStr & "Age"` and `SummWks.Cells(RwNum, 3).Formula = "=" & PathStr & "Size"`, etc.